# Invoking GDB with arguments

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

In the GDB manual, in the second chapter (Gettint In and Out of GDB), section 2.1 (Invoking GDB), it says:

> You can optionally have gdb pass any arguments after the executable
>   file to the inferior using --args. This option stops option
>   processing.
>
> `gdb --args gcc -O2 -c foo.c`

What does it mean? I don't see any executable files in the argument list. What is 'inferior'?

Edit: I suppose gcc is the executable we're debugging here. Is that correct. So does it mean that we are debugging the program gcc when run with the arguments "-O2 -c foo.c"?

Comment: The GDB manual has a glossary, have you tried to use it?

Comment: I didn't. will do that now. Thnkas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inferiors" are described in a different part of the documentation, under [4.9 Debugging Multiple Inferiors and Programs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html):

> `GDB` represents the state of each program execution with an object
>   called an inferior. An inferior typically corresponds to a process,
>   but is more general and applies also to targets that do not have
>   processes. Inferiors may be created before a process runs, and may be
>   retained after a process exits. Inferiors have unique identifiers that
>   are different from process ids. Usually each inferior will also have
>   its own distinct address space, although some embedded targets may
>   have several inferiors running in different parts of a single address
>   space. Each inferior may in turn have multiple threads running in it.

The part that you failed to quote then says:

> This will cause `gdb` to debug `gcc`, and to set `gcc`’s command-line
>   arguments (see
>   [Arguments](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Arguments.html#Arguments))
>   to ‘-O2 -c foo.c’.

`gcc` is the executable here.

Comment: yes I read that but I got confused with gcc there - I didn't think of it as the target program but instead as he compiler and that something is being passed to the compiler. I think it's clear to me now. thanks!